# How to use print with return in a function?

Tags: python

I wonder how I can return two different values with `print`.
The first `if` statement should return the argument `arg1`, the second `if` statement should return the text "It's not a number".
Can somebody give me a hint on how to solve the problem?

```
import sys

arg1 = (sys.argv[1])

def formatnumber(arg1):
    if type(arg1) == type(int()):
        return arg1
    if type(arg1) == type(str()):
        return "It's not a number"
formatnumber(arg1)

print arg1
```

Comment: Whats your expected output for a special input?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Usual behavior to filter out non-integer literals coming from user is to call `int(sys.argv[1])` and handle ValueError exception.

Comment: @Kasra If you use the script like this: ./myscript.py 10, It should output the number 10, and if you use it like this: ./myscript.py Kasra, It should output that Kasra is not a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python considers the command line arguments that u get from sys.argv[] as a string so u need to do pattern matching to find out whether the argument passed is a number or not. you should edit your program like this.

```
import sys
import re
def formatnumber(arg1) :
    pattern = "[0-9]+"
    if re.compile(pattern).match(arg1) :
        return arg1
    elif type(arg1) == type(str()):
        return "It's not a number"
if __name__=="__main__" :
    arg1=sys.argv[1]
    res = formatnumber(arg1)
    print res
```

this works as you require.

Comment: It accepts "a01" as a valid result (you need to use `match` instead of `search`) and condition `type(arg1) == type(str())` still doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @myaut thanq for the correction. yes we need to use `match` instead of `search` . well i just edited the program which was posted by Bruno Alves so i just left it as it is just for his easy understanding.

Answer (score 2):

> If you use the script like this: ./myscript.py 10, It should output the number 10, and if you use it like this: ./myscript.py Kasra, It should output that Kasra is not a number.

Like I mentioned in comment, you're doing it wrong. In Python correct way to say that some data is not expected is not returning a "special value" but raising an exception. Also note that Python doesn't automatically parses incoming arguments, so your function should look like this:

```
def formatnumber(arg1):
    arg1 = eval(arg1) # Never use a eval(), this is only an example
    if not isinstance(arg1, int):
        raise ValueError("not a number")
    return arg1
```

`int()` constructor already does that, so let language determine if incoming string can be coerced to integer and handle the errors.

Here is complete code for your script:

```
import sys

try:
    arg1 = int(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    print >> sys.stderr, "You didn't provide an argument"
    sys.exit(1)
except ValueError:
    print >> sys.stderr, "{} is not a valid integer".format(sys.argv[1])
    sys.exit(1)

# Work with arg1 like with integer, i.e.
print arg1 / 5
```

Comment: I get this error when I run your code:    print arg1 / 5
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @BrunoAlves: What version of interpreter are you using? Did you run exact copy of my code? I tested that in 2.7.6 before posting on SO.

Comment: I use Python 2.7.8, and i copied your code inside my function, with the print outside the function, like in my exemple.

Comment: @BrunoAlves: I've edited my answer, hope now you understand my point.

Comment: What should I use then: # Never use a eval(), this is only an example

Comment: Than I suggest to read some good book about Python, and return to that issue later. Or take each language construct from my script and ask Google about what it does. StackOverflow is not an interactive learning platform.

Comment: > What should I use then: < [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)